# PDF and Word extraction of text overlaid on images

Tags: image, pdf, apache-poi, pdfbox, docx

Tools used for processing content from PDF or Microsoft Word (DOC, DOCX), when parsing documents with images that have text labels overlaid on them, extract these labels separately to the images. The result is each such image being extracted without the overlaid text and then followed by one or more paragraphs of that text, out of context.

In such cases, an image like (a)

```
-------------
|  Level 2  |
-------------
|  Level 1  |
-------------
```

is extracted as (b)

```
-------------
|           |
-------------
|           |
-------------

Level 2
Level 1
```

This is "standard" behavior for tools used for `PDF` or `Word` processing, like Apache [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and [POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Is there any way of handling this, in the Apache tools, or any other similar tool?

The ideal solution would be to extract both the image and the labels as a single entity, like (a) above. Alternatively, image and label extraction could be deactivated together.

Ultimately, there should be way for avoiding the "pollution" of the document text with the labels, which otherwise appear out of content.

Comment: Apparently you want such a situation handled differently. But how exactly? You only present the situation you don't want...

Comment: The goal is to extract each image together with its labels (if any), or at least to avoid having any such labels appearing in the extracted document text. I have expanded the question to make this clearer. Thanks.

Comment: "to extract both the image and the labels as a single image": That would be **your** programming project then. That needs creating a new image where the labels are written **into** the extracted image. That is not what the `Word` document stores. There labels and image are separate things. "Ultimately, there should be way for avoiding the "pollution" of the document text with the labels": What document text gets polluted? The `Word` document stays unchanged. So to what other kind of document you try converting the `Word` document and why?

Comment: Similarly in pdfs, *extraction of images and text* from them usually is interpreted as *retrieving the image resources* as they are and *retrieving the arguments of text drawing instructions* after decoding. It usually is not interpreted to mean *manipulating the images to appear add they are transformed and combined in the pdf*. What you want is not easy, by the way, because you need to differentiate between text over images acting as labels of the image and text over a background image. Surely you don't want the text in the latter case be combined with the image, do you?

Comment: Having reviewed many tools that convert from one format to the other, none seems to be able to handle this, so obviously it is not an easy problem to solve. However, it is not an extravagant requirement, but a real problem in information extraction. What if one wants to parse a document with, say, chip pin diagrams and all the text in them are overlaid labels? Extraction will then yield multiple cryptic lines of a symbol each (like A0, C1 etc.). So yes, there is text "pollution", in that the document cannot be parsed into the discrete objects it should show to the user (text, tables, images).

Comment: Neither `PDF` nor `Word` documents are document formats that are suitable for information extraction. Both are documents for presentation to human readers. Exceptions on both are filled forms. There the filled form fields can be extracted to get informations. And that works very well for both document formats. One approach to solve that problem is storing the extractable informations on a meta level. For example most formats for `PDF` invoices have embedded `XML` which stores the extractable informations in machine readable form. The `PDF` is for human readers and the `XML` is for machines.

Comment: Of course. As I said, obviously it is not an easy problem to solve because `PDF` and `Word` formats are not parser-friendly. But the overlaid text problem results in a lot of "noise" in document extraction, so there should be a solution for it.

Comment: In case of pdfs, as long as the images in question are bitmap images, you can try to extract in a first pass the bitmap images including their positions and dimensions. In a second pass you can apply text extraction but filter out all text in those image areas. Beware, though, if you also have background images on which there is regular text, the approach will drop too much text.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that there is no way to suppress the overlaid text at any point, so multiple passes will not help in this case.